Etymology of ダンボール
This question has been on my mind for quite a while. The fact that ダンボール (corrugated cardboard) is written in katakana infers that it's a 外来語. However, it can also be written as 段ボール, and I have no idea what 段 in this context even means. Can someone enlighten me as to the etymology of that word?

Much of the time, Wikipedia or Wiktionary contains information like this; you may have to dig deeper for verification, but it can be a start. See 段ボール.

Basically 段 means the normal step.
Probably you should know 段々 first to understand it better:

１ いくつかの段のあるもの。また特に、階段。「裾が—になっているスカート」「石の—を上る」

I don't know how to describe it exactly, but for a visual example, "だんだんにつくられた田んぼ" refers to something like below (source)

Like above, 段々になっているスカート would refer to tiered skirts as seen in here.
So 段々になっている means stepping pattern on surface, and 段 in 段ボール means (one stripe of) corrugation used inside 段ボール. And as you can find online (e.g. here), ボール derives from board.
